# Deploying Node.js/Express Server through Intranet Static IP Address

Tags: node.js, express, web-services

So I'm basically moving over a node.js and express server from LocalHost to a static IP address on the intranet (not public internet yet so permissions can be handled later).

I feel pretty certain on the code I have written which is fairly simple by node.js standards. The goal is to serve static files, include API routes, and then start the express server though my Static IP while connected to a private VPN network ( I want it to work both through using a remote desktop and my own desktop). The server works fine locally but I can't get past that. I'm sure if the issue is coding related or firewall/permission related.

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();

// Serve static files from the dist folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist")));

// Include your API routes
app.use("/api", require("./functions/api"));

// Start the Express server with Static IP Address
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, "my-static-IP", () => {
  console.log("Server is running at http://my-static-IP:8080" + "\nPort Number: " + port);
});
```

Whenever I type in the static IP url through another computer I get a timed out error, and on the Remote Desktop I get the underlying architecture but not the full fledged webpage. I've included photos of both below. Any help would be great. I also included the network debugging checks.
[image: Desktop Error Page]
[image: Remote Desktop Page]
[image: Network Debugging Prompts]

Comment: Can you ping the server's IP address from the remote client desktop?  Can you tracert to the server's IP address?  This is basic network debugging to first just see if you have network communication to that IP address from the remote client.

Comment: Both show network communication the only exception being the network ping showed min, max, and average response as 0ms but no errors otherwise. I edited the post above to show both of those.

Comment: In your screenshot, what's the "Ping request could not find host xxx"?  Isn't that showing a problem?  FYI, never put a port number on a ping request.   You should pass "ping" only a DNS name or an IP address, no port.  Ping uses the ICMP protocol (not TCP) which doesn't have ports.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. The could not find host was from when I included the port number.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using IP for host, store `ip` into .env file.

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const host = process.env.PORT || "192.88.66.66" //your ip(use ENV file for that)
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080; //port

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist")));


app.use("/api", require("./functions/api"));


app.listen(port, host, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running at http://${host}:${port}"`);
});
```

Comment: This is so helpful, thanks! Now I just have to work on making that ENV file.